# Surface pro 3 tablets have identical Win10 product keys? Should I be worried?

Tags: windows-10, microsoft-surface-pro-3

I have two Surface Pro 3 in different configurations (i3/i5). Both have been upgraded from Win 8.1 to Win 10. Each purchased from a different vendor.

In my backup and cataloguing procedure, I save hard drive images and software registration info for both. Both tablets appear to have identical Windows 10 serial numbers and product registration keys. This makes me uneasy, as I might have trouble activating after drive formats and reinstalls.

Should I contact Microsoft to sort this out, or is this completely acceptable?

Comment: No; The behavior you describe is 100% normal; Research this topic a little, and you will find, that everyone who accepted the free offer got a generic key.  You will not have any problems installing Windows 10 if you have to format your SP3 your licenSE is a digital entitlement connected to the motherboard

Comment: I've read about this before, the motherboard licensing stuff, and I really do not understand how it works and how that can be reliable. Suppose it is not surface, but an off-the-shelf desktop. How can it work when motherboard must be replaced, or how can it work when the system is moved to new hardware entirely? I have started up windows 8 installations before when moving hdd to an entirely different system, but that just doesn't settle in my head.

Comment: If you "move" to entirely different hardware, you would need a new Windows 10 license.  Here is a good article that can help clarify things for you:  [How to Use Your Free Windows 10 License After Changing Your PC’s Hardware](http://www.howtogeek.com/226510/how-to-use-your-free-windows-10-license-after-changing-your-pc%e2%80%99s-hardware/)

Comment: @Nomenator a motherboard bought at a brick and mortar store or Newegg would be the same, at least for Windows 10 is a digital entitlement.  An OEM product like a surface pro has its license stored in its ACPI table for the version it came with but the free upgrade license is still a digital entitlement.  If you want a literal Windows 10 license key you would have to purchase a retail copy of Windows 10.  The license to Windows 10 is forever locked to that specific device.  If you had to replace the motherboard you would have to purchase Windows 10

Comment: It has been several days since we heard from you. Did you have any lingering questions?

Comment: @Run5k no, questions didn't come up, really. Just a general state of confusion. I guess across different ways to activate there is no real problem accessing it, but this seems not customer friendly of MS to distribute licenses this way.

Comment: It's all a matter of perspective.  Once you understand the basic concepts behind the activation matrix that I posted below, it is relatively simple.  In your particular scenario, both of your machines received the free upgrade from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, so they each have a digital license that doesn't require a product key.  As I said before, when/if you need to perform a full wipe and reload on those devices, you can simply skip the screens that ask for product key input and they will automatically activate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While I admire your thorough backup and cataloging procedures, you don't have anything to worry about.

Whatever method you utilized to determine each Surface Pro's local product key simply found the generic, post-upgrade key.  In reality, your activation on each of those devices is a digital license.  As a result, when/if you need to perform a full wipe and reload on those devices, they will automatically activate.  Here is a good reference from Microsoft themselves:

[Activation in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12440/windows-10-activation)

[image: Digital License]